# underbrace and phantom

Tags: math-mode, spacing

With the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\underbrace{a+b}_\textrm{text}+ \underbrace{\frac{a+b}{c}}_\textrm{text}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\underbrace{a+b\phantom{\frac{a}{c}}}_\textrm{text}+ \underbrace{\frac{a+b}{c}}_\textrm{text}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I obtain

[image]

I do not understand the extra horizontal space in the second equation. Can you explain? How to get rid of it?

Comment: use `\vphantom` instead of `\phantom` in there. `\phantom` affects horizontal and vertical lengths. `\vpahntom` affects only vertical (that is the wanted in your case)

Comment: Works nice. I thought that `\phantom` was at the same time `\vphantom` and `\hphantom`. You may want to post an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: `\phantom` is at the same time `\vphantom` and `\hphanom`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\phantom` is at the same time `\vphantom` [vertical phantom space  (->vertical space with invisible content)] and `\hphanom` [horizontal phantom space (->horizontal space with invisible content)]...

So your command in the second equation, except the vertical space that would be needed by the fraction creates and the horizontal too.

To understand these commands, just think that everything in there will be printed without ink [or exactly on the background colors, even if the background will be a photo (with changing and many colors)]... So, prints something invisible (without real printing anything).

Use `\vphantom` instead in there...